Move /home partition from separate drive to same drive as root
My Linux Mint install currently has my /home directory set up as a separate partition on a second drive mounted at /home.  I see a lot of tutorials for switching /home to another drive, but I'd like to do the reverse; create a /home directory on my root filesystem drive and use that as my /home directory, removing the second drive that /home is currently pointing to.  Can this be done, and if so, what's the procedure for doing it?

Are you suggesting that you want to merge / & /home or that you create another partition for the new /home on the same disk as / ?

Merge, I think.  I have a root partition which I want to use to contain the /home directory.

If you do not mount /home, it automatically creates a new /home inside / with default settings. You then could manually mount the old /home partition & rsync all your data back. I prefer to keep /home inside /, but have all data like Documents, Downloads, Music, etc in a separate data partition. You are reversing this: Move Home &   Separate data partition

@oldfred I wouldn't know what would create a new /home; and if it's not there, your login attempts would just faill.


Can this be done

Yes, and it's not very hard. Multiple ways, it might be easiest if you just copy over the contents of your current home to the /home directory on the volume that hosts / from a live boot image
I'd say you do the following:

Boot from a live medium. For example, the Fedora installers USB media work just fine.
Once there, figure out what your root and home volumes are, for example using lsblk. In this example, say your / resides on /dev/nvme0n0p0, and your your home on /dev/nvme0n0p1.
Mount these: sudo mkdir /originalroot /originalhome; sudo mount /dev/nvme0n0p0 /originalroot; sudo mount /dev/nvme0n0p1 /originalhome.
Recursive copy all the contents of /originalhome/ to  temporary /originalroot/home: sudo cp -ar /originalhome/* /originalroot/home/.
Edit your /originalroot/etc/fstab (for example, sudo nano /originalroot/etc/fstab and comment out (prepend with #) the line that describes /home. (This now means that on the next boot, your separate partition won't be mounted over /home. It's then just a normal directory on the root volume with files in it.)
reboot

The good thing is, because you're just copying, there's never a point where you might lose data; if something goes wrong, just undo step 5, and you're in the "before" situation.

This procedure worked great!  I had to end up mounting the perhaps more standardly named /dev/sda1 to /originalroot/ and /dev/sdb1 to /originalhome/.

the /dev/nvme{device number}n{namespace number}p{partition number} naming scheme is extremely standard – it's what you get when your computer has an NVMe SSD. /dev/sd{letter} is only normal for SCSI/SATA devices
